# Easy persistent network config on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, ifconfig, network-interface

I'm having some problems configuring a static IP on my ubuntu server. What is the easiest way to configure IP, netmask, nameserver and default gateway on `eth0`?
I've tried modifying the `/etc/network/interfaces`file but the interface goes down after reboot. I need to do this in CLI.

This is what the file looks like (without the comments):

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 172.16.61.4
    netmask 255.255.255.192
    nameserver 172.16.61.2
    broadcast 172.16.61.63
```

EDIT:
It seems to work now. However, nslookup doesn't find any matches at all. Local nslookups on the 2008 server running dns works.

Comment: That's the correct place to do it, perhaps you should include the content of that file in your question. Maybe its just missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nameserver should be placed in /etc/resolv.conf, exactly as you have it above.

Also, add the domain name used in the local network, to avoid having to use fqdn for lookups:

```
domain local
nameserver 172.16.61.2
```

Replace  `local` with whatever your local domain is.

Comment: It's a switched LAN so no gateway should be needed, right? I'm still able to ping when I start the interface again.

Comment: Sorry @FilipHaglund, I don't follow your question.  If you need to access anything outside of the local lan, you need routing.  If you need to access the internet, you need a default gateway.  Can you post an `/sbin/ifconfig -a` before and after you bring the interface up, along with a `netstat -rn` after?

Comment: It's a local network without internet access. Routing table shows eth0 as default gateway and ping works. Nslookup doesn't.

Comment: Ah right.  Your question asks where the default gateway should be configured.  I have altered my answer in response to your new information

Comment: Missed your `/etc/resolv.conf`. I was adding the nameserver to `/etc/network/interfaces` file. Guess I'm too used to having links formatted `like this`. It works now though! Thanks!